# Installing cordova plugin in MFPF 7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-studio

can we install Cordova plugin "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine" in MFPF 7.1

If Yes, can someone please advise what steps we need to follow.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine plugin needs `cordova-ios >4.0.0.`

where as MobileFirst CLI contains an instance of Cordova `CLI v5.0.0`, and iOS platform version `3.7.0`.
for more details see here : [link](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/hello-world/integrating-mfpf-sdk-in-cordova-applications/)

So it may not work.Try  below command if it works

> mfp cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine` plugin in your MFP 7.1 Cordova Application by following [this blog](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/08/03/integrating-3rd-party-cordova-plug-ins/) if the app is built using Mobilefirst Studio Plugin.

If it is MFP 7.1 pure cordova application, you can add wkwebview plugin by running following command in terminal.

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine`

**Note** : MobileFirst Features like Direct Update, Server Notifications might stop working if you are using wkwebview plugin.